# Prove that the following polynomials are irreducible:

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

Prove that the following polynomials are irreducible:

$x^6 − y(y − 1)x^4 + (y − 1)x^3 − (y^2 − 2y + 1)x + y − 1 \in R[x, y]$

i factor it into $x^6-y(y-1)x^4+(y-1)y^3 -((y-1)^2)x+(y-1) $

I don't know what to do next, is there anything to do $(y-1)$?

Comment: Is this like Eisenstein's criterion with $y-1$ being the prime?

Comment: i don't know. can i do this ?

Comment: $R[x,y] \cong R[y][x]$ so you can interpret this as a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients in $y$. The polynomial $y-1$ is prime (in R[y]) and and the given polynomial satisfies all the conditions to apply Eisenstein.